# Application of binomial theorem and pascal's triangle

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

I am having difficulties understanding, and subsequently solving this problem:

"Suppose that b is an integer with b ≥ 7. Use the binomial theorem and the appropriate row of Pascal’s triangle to find the base-b expansion of (11)4
b [that is, the fourth power of the number (11)b in base-b notation]."

I am familiar with the binomial theorem as well as pascal's triangle, but I am confused how to properly apply them to this problem.

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $11$ in base $b$ notation means $b+1$, and note that
$$(b+1)^4=b^4+4b^3+6b^2+4b+1.$$

Comment: So if $b\geq 6$ then $ [(11)_b]^4=( 14641)_b$.

Comment: Almost right. It has to be $b\gt 6$.  For if $b=6$ then the middle is not a legitimate digit, there is "carrying" and we get $15041$. But the problem specified $b\ge 7$, so everything is fine.

Comment: It was late.  I should have written 7,not 6 ,obviously.